# How to test if a value is `omit`?

Tags: ansible

I need to filter out `omit` values from a list, such as:

```yaml
# host_vars file
my_list:
- foo
- omit
- bar
```

to get list `['foo', 'bar']`.

I tried `my_list|reject('eq', omit)` as well as `my_list|reject('sameas', omit)`, but neither worked. It appears as if `omit` values (at least the ones used in different parts of a playbook) are different.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was quite a silly mistake.  In the YAML file `omit` is just a plain string. To pass the special variable it has to be enclosed in the templating braces `{{ }}`:

```yaml
# host_vars file
my_list:
- foo
- "{{ omit }}"
- bar
```

Then `|reject('eq', omit)` works as expected!